# clearing textbox from multiple textboxes on a form on a click of a button

Tags: c#

Not sure how to select a textbox from multiple textboxes on a form and clear it on the click event of a button. For example, if we have multiple operand fields for a calculator and need to implement clear current field button, how do I implement it? Here is the code snippet I have so far.

```
private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e) 
{ 
   foreach (Control t in this.Controls) 
   { 
      if (t is TextBox) 
      { 
         if (t.Focused) 
         { 
            t.Text = ""; 
         } 
      } 
   } 
}
```

Comment: When the button clicked focus will be moved out `TextBox` so this code will not work, you have to find the control by either `name` or `tag`

Comment: It's actually a very simple program. Just put two textboxes on a form and a button. Now try to get hold of the active textbox on the click of a button. If I knew beforehand which one I want, then it's easy. If I don't know, not sure which event to catch, mouse leave, focus, or something else.

Comment: @HariPrasad, if I knew the name, then it's easy. The problem is I don't know which one is active, means in which I had focus or which one was active before moving away from it and clicking the button. Not sure about how tag works.

Comment: @AlexJolig Apologies, added code to the main post.

Comment: See if this is what you are looking for http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4428100/find-out-the-control-with-last-focus

Comment: The link which @MarkHall provided is the solution you need.

Comment: Nope none of the solution mentioned on the link are working. :(

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One option could be subscribing to `TextBox` `LostFocus` event.

Declare a class field to hold the reference of active `TextBox`.

private TextBox activeTextbox;

in `Form_Load` event subscribe to `TextBox` `LostFocus` event.

```
textbox1.LostFocus += (se,ev) => activeTextbox = textbox1;
textbox2.LostFocus += (se,ev) => activeTextbox = textbox2;
```

Now in button `click` event

```
private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e) 
{
     if(activeTextbox != null)
     {
          activeTextbox.Text = "";    
     }

}
```

Comment: its better to use `GotFocus` or `enter` events instead of `GotFocus` event. because when a button is `acceptButton` of form, user can click and fire click event by pressing enter button even when another textBox is active.

Answer (score 0):

As Hari Prasad mentioned, the active TextBox will lose the focus as soon as user clicks on the button. So I suggest using `Leave` event and an instance to detect which TextBox has been active before the button has been clicked.

```
private TextBox _tmpTextbox;

private void txt1_Leave(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
   _tmpTextbox = txt1;
}

private void txt2_Leave(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
  _tmpTextbox = txt2;
}
```

And for the button:

```
private void btnTest_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
  _tmpTextbox.Text = "";
}
```

In order to shortened the code, you can use one even handler for all the textboxes:

```
private void txt1_Leave(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
  TextBox activeTextBox = (TextBox) sender;
  _tmpTextbox = activeTextBox;
}
```

Comment: Tried, _tmpTextbox is null in button click event. :(

Comment: @SaurabhGupta Are you sure you clicked the button after a textbox got the focus? Itried the code and it worked fine.

Comment: Yeah that's what I did. :(

Comment: Not sure what the problem was with this solution. Thanks for your help though!