# Detect if focus was received after Keyboard Tab key was pressed

Tags: c#, wpf

I need to have logic to handle an element's `GotKeyboardFocus` event and distinguish whether it was triggered by the Tab key or by some other way. But I know there is only the generalized event `GotKeyboardFocus`. How can I detect if the focus was received by pressing the Tab key inside the event handler method? Or is there another event?

Comment: It might be helpful to know why you want to use different logic.

Comment: @OldBoyCoder Yes, for example , this event is invoked when modal window closed and mouse cursor is above textbox, in this case there is no need for doing something

Comment: I'm not a WPF expert but I see that the KeyboardFocusChangedEventArgs parameter to the event has a Device property (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.input.inputeventargs.device?view=netframework-4.7.2#System_Windows_Input_InputEventArgs_Device).  Is that any use?  The alternative is setting some global in your modal close event that could be detected in the GotKeyboardFocus

Comment: You have to do it manually. Simply [track](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4428100/1997232) the focus. Reset it when dialog is popping up.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to subscribe to the `GotFocus` or `GotKeyboardfocus` event and then check for pressed keys:

```
<TextBox GotFocus="UIElement_OnGotFocus"/>
```

In the handler:

```
if (Keyboard.PrimaryDevice.IsKeyDown(Key.Tab))
{
  // Do something when Tab is pressed
}
```

Maybe you like to extend the TextBox class to handle this event without attaching eventhandlers in XAML.

```
public class CustomTextBox : TextBox
{
  protected override void OnGotFocus (System.Windows.RoutedEventArgs e)
  {
    if (Keyboard.PrimaryDevice.IsKeyDown(Key.Tab))
    {
      // Do something when Tab is pressed
    }
  }
}
```